# Can Eclipse have one output console for each thread that i generate?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Here it's my code:

```
int port = 1111;
    for (String string : categories) {
        ServerMulticastAsta s = new ServerMulticastAsta("Asta " + string, portaAscolto);
        Thread thread = new Thread(s);
        thread.start();
        port += 1111;
    } // fine for
```

I was asking if can i have in Eclipse one different console output for the thread that i generate in this portion of code; otherwise i would see the output of the threads in the GeneratorThreadClass and because of they're multicast server you could imagine the amounth of traffic that they create.

Comment: No, System.out is unique. Have you though about using a logger like log4j to push to different log files?

Comment: Actually not yet, but i've heard about log4j, what good is it for? @jhamon

Comment: The answer is not to depend on the console, but rather to create different `Stream`s / `Writer`s for each thread. These streams can go to the file system, to a ByteArrayOutputStream, Database, etc.